# How to solve this 2nd ODE with simple inequality constraints numerically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

I have a 2nd ODE (derived from an elastic rod deflated naturally under its self-weight):
$$
y'' + K (x - 1) \cos(y) = 0 
$$

K is a constant coefficient. The variables range between $x \in [0, 1], y \in [-\pi / 2, 0]$

The BCs:
$$
y(0) = 0 \\
y'(1) = 0
$$
and **a constraint** $y' \le 0$ and $y'' \ge 0$ (from physical meaning).

---

*How can I solve it numerically?*

I have a weak background in the theory/classfication of ODEs, but I still tried to analysis and solve it as followed:

## 1. My own analysis on this problem

This is an second order nonlinear ODE. Its BCs are located in two sides, so it is a BVP.

A common practice is to split it into a 1st ODE system:
$$
\begin{cases}
y_2 = y_1' \\
y_2' + K (x - 1) \cos (y_1) = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Then I discrete all derivates by explicit euler method, and employe `shooting method`(where I guess the init BCs y'(0) and adjust this guess for a satisfying solution).

When K is big, I can solve it properly. But when K is small, my shooting method always failed. I have no idea how to analysis it anymore.

## 2. My questions

1. Is my judgement about this problem correct? Is it an 2nd order ODE, Bounday value problems with not enough BCs?
2. Why I can solve it properly in non-stiff case, and fail in stiff case?
3. Some literatures point out that, `auto07p` package can help me on this problem. But I cannot understand its manual even a bit. Which book should I read to handle this problem?
4. How can I know whether this problem have a solution?
5. How to solve this problem numerically?

Sorry for my weak background in ODE.

Thanks a lot for your time!

## 3. `solve_bvp` and `shooting` failed when K > 200 and ignore the constraint

When K > 200, we need to set up a special init guess for `solve_bvp`, otherwise we will fail. Please check @Lutz 's answer below.
$
[image: 2022-04-11-21-59-47]

Comment: What is your programming environment? Matlab as bvp4c, python has scipy.integrate.solve_bvp, I think in Mathematica you can use the generic ODE solver, etc.

Comment: For small $K$ in a first approach $y$ is small, so $y''(x)\approx K(1-x)$, $y'(x)\approx y'(1)-\frac{K}{2}(1-x)^2$, so that $y'(0)=-\frac{K}{2}$ is an "inspired" initial guess. // In single shooting if one direction proves instable you might get a better result starting from the other interval end.

Comment: Thanks Lutz for your quick reply! I work in cpp and python. I will take a look now about  `scipy.integrate.solv_bvp`. Also, I will try another end in my shooting method.

Comment: I will post my result there as soon as I finished it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you do

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linspace, logspace, exp, cos

K = 5

ode = lambda x,y: [ y[1], K*(1-x)*cos(y[0]) ]
bc = lambda y0,y1: [ y0[0], y1[1] ]

x = linspace(0,1,5)
y = [0*x]*2
res = solve_bvp(ode, bc, x, y, tol=1e-5)

print(res.message)

x = linspace(0,1,150)
y = res.sol(x)
plt.plot(x,y[0])
plt.plot(res.x,res.y[0],'x')
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

The solver uses a multi-shot approach where the segments are encoded using a collocation method. This produces a huge non-linear system that is solve via Newton using sparse linear algebra.

[image]

For large $K$ you get a nearly singular DE, so that a boundary layer approach becomes advisable for the initial guess. The outer solution is $y=-\frac{\pi}2$ (or any other root of the cosine). The inner solution at the left boundary with $Y(s)=y(K^{-1/2}s)$ follows the approximate DE
$$
Y''(s)=K^{-1}y''(K^{-1/2}s)\approx\cos(Y(s))
$$
This has a stable solution that approximately looks like $\frac\pi2(e^{-s}-1)$. So put that as initial guess

```
x = logspace(-6,0,21); x[0]=0;
y = [ pi/2*(exp(-x*K**0.5)-1),pi/2*K**0.5*exp(-x*K**0.5) ]
```

and I still get a solution for $K=500$,

[image]

$K=5000$ works too. It is also sufficient to simplify the initial guess to

```
x = logspace(-6,0,21); x[0]=0;
y = [0*x-pi/2, 0*x]
```

Comment: Thanks Lutz! It's exactly what I want.

Comment: As you instructed, I just finish the code and got your reply notification. Really thank you.

Comment: Hi Lutz, I just run the code. It works well when K < 200. But when K =300, it fails. Would you please give me some advice?

Comment: The problem is that the initial phase is somewhat a mathematical pendulum. If the first solver steps are too enthusiastic you get a rotating solution that can not be made to stop at the equilibrium. Setting the initial guess at the equilibrium, with or without initial ramp, removes that wrong behavior. See my additions on variants of a working initial guess

Comment: Yes sir. I really really appreciate your profound knowledge and your understanding. Thanks for your help! I will struggle to learn more.